# Php Ajax Form is not submitting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

Hey guys I am creating a newsletter sign-up form and trying to submit it with AJAX..

Here is my form:

```
<div id="form-content">
  <form method="POST" id="news-form" name="newsletter">
     <div class="bd-input-2 form-group">
        <input type="email" name="newsletter_email" placeholder="Enter your email address" required />
     </div>             
     <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" name="newsletter">Submit</button>
     </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

And this one is my JS file in same page as form:

```
$('#news-form').submit(function(e){     
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'newsletter-submit.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $(this).serialize()
    })
    .done(function(data){
        $('#form-content').fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $('#form-content').fadeIn('slow').html(data);
            console.log(data);
        });
    })
    .fail(function(){
        alert('Ajax Submit Failed ...');    
    });
});
```

On console nothing is displaying not even an error just an empty line.

And my newsletter-submit.php file :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['newsletter'])){
    $newsletter_email = filter_var($_POST['newsletter_email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);    
    if(filter_var($newsletter_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $newsletter_email = filter_var($newsletter_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
        $em_check = sqlsrv_query($con, "SELECT email FROM newsletter_signups WHERE email='$newsletter_email'",array(), array("Scrollable"=>"buffered"));
        $num_rows = sqlsrv_num_rows($em_check); 
        if($num_rows > 0){
            echo "<br/><p style='color: #fff;'>Email exist in our newsletter list.</p>";
        }else{
            $query = "INSERT INTO newsletter_signups (email) VALUES ('{$newsletter_email}')";
            $insert_newsletter_query = sqlsrv_query($con,$query);
            echo '<br/><p style="color: green;">Thank you for sign up in our newsletter</p>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

But if I add any code after **php tags** e.g `Hello world` that is displayed after the submission.

My php code was working before AJAX file

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: Your input field is named `newsletter_email` and in your php you are checking for `isset($_POST['newsletter'])`

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yes I run it on web-server Windows R2012 I have Jquery library and I get no error

Comment: change your `.submit` into `click`

Comment: as mentioned, changing to `if(isset($_POST['newsletter_email'])){` should sort it. Basically it never gets into this `if` block, so no query is run and consequently nothing is returned.

Comment: @Gagantous no, why would you do that? It's handling the submission of the form, which is correct.

Comment: oh sorry with that

Comment: @emed Oh my god I am really stupid.. That was the problem the name... can you give it as answer to accept as solve... Thank you

Comment: Please change this   <button type="submit" name="newsletter" value="1">Submit</button>

Comment: try to add `.beforesend` and `.beforeSucces` to see the error to help you identified the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input field is named `newsletter_email` and in your php you are checking for `isset($_POST['newsletter'])` which is always false.

Comment: @Maria To avoid this implement the else's , because you will get another empty response if `filter_var($newsletter_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` returns false